# How do I close several browsers after a Selenium test run?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-chrome, selenium, testng

I'm using a setup of Selenium/TestNG with Java in Eclipse and Chrome as my browser. Whenever I start a script with TestNG methods I get an empty Chrome page which I assume is the "parent" window for the driver itself. Then, as my test methods navigate somewhere I get a second Chrome window that opens the actual page I navigated to. After all tests, at teardown, I'm trying to close everything with driver.quit, but this only closes one of the browsers.

Is there a reasonably simple way (I'm a beginner with Java, Selenium and TestNG) to close all the opened browsers?

Here is a simplified version of the code I have currently. I use one base class and another class extending the baseclass. The second class has all the test methods in it.

```
package TestNG;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import java.lang.Runtime;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


    public class BaseClass {

        public WebDriver driver;

        public BaseClass(){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/foo/Downloads/chromedriver");
            System.setProperty("restart.browser.each.scenario", "false");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }   


        @BeforeSuite
        public void setup() {
            System.out.println("Running beforesuite.");
        }

        @AfterSuite
        public void teardown() {
            System.out.println("Running aftersuite.");
            driver.quit(); 
        }
    }
```

And the second class with the test methods:

```
package TestNG;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.testng.asserts.*;

public class Userstories extends TestNG.BaseClass {

    @Test
    public void NavToURL() {
        this.driver.get("https:/url.url.se/");
        String expectedTitle = ”Hello”;
        String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedTitle,actualTitle); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your test must be starting two drivers somehow, and abandoning one, because only one window should be opened, and driver.quit() should close all windows associated with that driver,

Comment: Thank you Mobrockers! You made me look at the problem from another angle. The reason I got two windows was because I initialized the driver in the constructor of the base class (see code above) and then included the baseclass in the xml calling all the test methods. I removed Baseclass from the xml, and now I get only one window which closes after the tests. Woohoo!

Comment: @A.Warrby if you are just beginning to use selenium, you might want to check the project that I'm working on. It simplifies selenium setup and make your tests easier to compose. https://github.com/codezombies/easytest